# Trouble hiding nav bar with react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm having trouble disabling the navbar when I'm in the sign up page. I only want the navbar to show after my user finishes login which has the route '/ '. Any help would be much appreciated.

```js
  render() {
    return (
        <App>
          <Main>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div>
                    <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                        <ul className="navbar-nav">
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <NavLink to={"/"} className="nav-link" href="#">Log In</NavLink>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <NavLink to={"/home"} className="nav-link" href="#">Home</NavLink>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <NavLink to={"/"} className="nav-link" href="#">Log Out</NavLink>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                    <div className="content">
                        <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Splash />} />
                        <Route exact path="/main" render={() => <Main />} />
                        <Route exact path="/signup" render={() => <Signup />} />
        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
          </Main>
        </App>
    );
}
```

Comment: Which set of routes *should* it render for? Which set of routes should it *not* render for? If you can choose a subset then you can wrap the Nav in another `<Route>` and render it only for specific routes.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect the current route you are on by using `this.props.location.pathname`.

Then setting 
`{this.props.location.pathname !== '/signup' && <nav> ... </nav>}` will mean you will only show the nav if the view condition is satisfied. To find out more about view conditional logic check out [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

If you find your app grows more complex. You could setup a PrivateRoute as per https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow
This will mean you can treat Routes different purely based if the user has logged in or not.